# sum of a calculated column in foreach

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql table

service_charges

```
id service_name service_charges
```

I use a mysql query like

```
select service_name service, service_charges,count(service_name)as unit 
from service charges group_by service
```

in php file I am using

```
foreach(services as service){
echo $service['service'];
echo $service['service_charges'];
echo $service['unit'];
$service_charges_total = (($service['service_charges'])*($service['unit']));
echo $sevice_charges_total;
}
```

I am getting the result like this:
[image]

Now How can I get the total for $service_charges_total(amount column) i.e. I want a total of 4200+1200 + 350 = 5750.

Thanks.

Comment: $serviceTotalAmount += $service_charges_total;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it at php at your function like this

```
$total=0;
foreach(services as service)
{
   echo $service['service'];
   echo $service['service_charges'];
   echo $service['unit'];
   $service_charges_total = (($service['service_charges'])*($service['unit']));
   echo $sevice_charges_total;
   $total+=$sevice_charges_total;
}
echo $total;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select service_name as service, 
       service_charges,
       count(service_name) as unit,
       (select sum(service_charges) from service) as total_amount
from service as charges 
group_by service, 
         service_charges
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT sum(Amount) from service_charges;
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this work for you

Store the amount value in array and then use array_sum()

```
$service_charges_total = (($service['service_charges'])*($service['unit']));
$array[]=$service_charges_total;
$total_sum=array_sum($array);
echo $total_sum;
```